# Aggregating columns by finding the difference between 2 dates in r

Tags: r, date, aggregate

I need to use the aggregate function to reduce table 1 below to table 2 by finding the difference in max(end date) and min(start date) for each ID. I have tried several codes but this is the latest;

```
Table2<-aggregate(table1$date,by=list(table1$ID),FUN=diff)
as.numeric(Table2)
```

---

```
   #Table1
       ID      Date
    1  100 1/10/1999
    2  100 1/10/1999
    3  100  4/7/2000
    4  100  4/8/2000
    5  100  3/7/2001
    6  110  3/8/2001
    7  110  4/8/2002
    8  110  4/6/2003
    9  110  4/7/2003
    10 110  3/6/2005
```

Desired outcome

```
Table 2
ID  length(days)
100  788
110  1459
```

Comment: You should add a reprucible dtaset, and your own code.

Comment: I have tried several r codes but this is the latest -                                            Table2<-aggregate(Table1$date,by=list(Table1$ID),FUN=diff) as.numeric(Table2)

Comment: please add it to your question. Also use `dput` to make a dataset

Comment: @Salman, I have used dput to create a text file of the data. do I attach it to my question as an image? I couldnt find an attach document option

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your own code, data and desired output to get the answers that are most usefull to you...

Below is a `data.table` approach that calculates duration per ID, based on the first and last entry of each ID-group.

```
library( data.table )

df <- data.frame( date = c(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-02-04"), as.Date("2018-01-02"), as.Date("2018-02-04") ),
                  id = c(100,100,110,110),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df
#         date  id
# 1 2018-01-01 100
# 2 2018-02-04 100
# 3 2018-01-02 110
# 4 2018-02-04 110

setDT(df)[, difftime( date[.N], date[1] ), by = id][]
#     id      V1
# 1: 100 34 days
# 2: 110 33 days
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but this might be difficult to apply when i have  date and ID columns with 15,000 data points and 10-15 dates per ID

Answer (score 0):

Base R and `aggregate` will do it easily.
But first coerce your `Date` column to class `Date`.

```
table1$Date <- as.Date(table1$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")

aggregate(Date ~ ID, table1, function(x) x[length(x)] - x[1])
#   ID  Date
#1 100  787 
#2 110 1459
```

**Data.**

```
table1 <- read.table(text = "
ID      Date
1  100 1/10/1999
2  100 1/10/1999
3  100  4/7/2000
4  100  4/8/2000
5  100  3/7/2001
6  110  3/8/2001
7  110  4/8/2002
8  110  4/6/2003
9  110  4/7/2003
10 110  3/6/2005
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach with `dplyr`, assuming you've converted Date to a date-type field already, per Rui's answer.

```
library(dplyr)
summary <- table1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(min = min(Date),
            max = max(Date)) %>%
  mutate(range = max - min + 1)

summary
# A tibble: 2 x 4
     ID min        max        range 
  <int> <date>     <date>     <time>
1   100 1999-01-10 2001-03-07 788   
2   110 2001-03-08 2005-03-06 1460
```